# How do I make my own Hyperstake coin

Tags: altcoin, genesis-block

So ive forked the code but seems to be connected to the old coin stuff.

What I am looking to do is fork their code and create my own coin! I know that I need to make a node but I can't find any process that shows me how to create my own coin.

Please help

Comment: What the hell is hyperstake?

Comment: I remember reading something about this a while ago (for a different altcoin), and it said you need at least 2 nodes configured to communicate with each other. Maybe that helps? It may differ depending on which altcoin codebase you start with though.

Comment: Yes that def pointed me into the right direction! Anyone know how to setup checkpoint to send a certain amount of the moneysupply to certain addresses as soon as I run the node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to disable dns seeds

use `connect=<ip_of_other_node>`

instead `addnode=<ip_of_other_node>` in you `coin.conf` file.

Comment: did you manage to get it working ?

Comment: I did but trying to setup a premine for a pos.. Decided to fork blackcoin but no idea how that works yet